# Replace/Mask text at particular position in a textBox field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

How to replace text entered in a textbox with **`*`** after entering next character using Java Script?

I'm using **`inputSecret`** tag for that textbox but it immediately hides the whole content when I type.

This is what I'm doing now: (which is wrong. Can we tweak this inputSecret tag?)

```
<h:inputSecret maxlength="6" value="#{userBean.field}" />
```

**Requirements:**

- It should take the actual value in managed bean property but mask
  it with **`"*"`** only in the UI.
- It should mask the text at particular position. For ex, first 2 and last 2 characters are masked but middle 2 characters are displayed like  `**34**`
- It should start masking only from the moment I enter second character. Let's say this is the value which I'm entering **`123456`**.

  - First step: **`1`**
  - Second step: **`*2`**
  - Third step: **`**3`**
  - Fourth step: **`**34`** (as 3rd and 4th characters are not supposed to be masked)
  - Fifth step: **`**345`**
  - Sixth step: **`**34*6`**
  - Seventh step: **`**34**`** (by the time I finish entering in this textBox)

Any leads on how to do this?

**PS: This field can be alphanumeric. I used numeric values just as an example.**

Comment: Better to 'hide' it also after a timeout... Do both. And why not 'copy' the value in the bean and mask the copy there... ? Then someone cannot do a 'view source'  to get the real value (e.g. when the system is left unattended by the person that started entering the data)?

Answer (score 0):

If we close our eyes and disregard security issues, there is a way to do this with JavaScript only.

### IDEA

Basic idea is taken from this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186309/make-password-textbox-value-visible-after-each-character-input). Knowing that `<h:inputSecret ../>` is actually rendered as `<input type="password".../>`, we can use java script to manipulate with it on following way:

- when page is ready in browser, create hidden `input` with same `name` attribute as original one so that JSF cannot see any difference,
- change *type* of original `input` from *password* to *text*,
- use java script to intercept typed chars and use original field for UI rendering and hidden field for holding value that will be submitted to backing bean

### IMPLEMENTATION

#### xhtml

```
<h:form class="form">
    <h:inputSecret maxlength="6" value="#{userBean.field}" class="pass"/>
</h:form>
```

#### javascript (using jQuery library)

```
//creating mask from real value according to required steps
function createMask(value) {
    var mask = "";
    var valueLen = value.length;
    if (valueLen === 1) {
        mask = value;
    } else if (valueLen === 2) {
        mask = "*" + value.substring(1, 2);
    } else if (valueLen === 3) {
        mask = "**" + value.substring(2, 3);
    } else if (valueLen === 4) {
        mask = "**" + value.substring(2, 4);
    } else if (valueLen === 5) {
        mask = "**" + value.substring(2, 5);
    } else if (valueLen === 6) {
        mask = "**" + value.substring(2, 4) + "**";
    }
    //if maxLength>6 then add more else ifs
    return mask;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer = "";
    //add hidden field to hold actual typed value
    $(".form").append($('<input type="hidden" class="hidpassw" />'));
    //give hidden field the same name as original
    $(".hidpassw").attr("name", $(".pass").attr("name"));
    //change original type from password to text and remove name property
    $(".pass").attr("type", "text").removeAttr("name");
    //get maxlength attr value of original field
    var maxLength = parseInt($(".pass").attr("maxlength"));

    //alphanumeric chars are added to value
    $("body").on("keypress", ".pass", function (e) {
        var code = e.which;
        var length = $(".hidpassw").val().length;
        //modify regex if it doesnt fit your 'alphanumeric' definition
        if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/i.test(String.fromCharCode(code))) {
            //check if maxLength is not reached
            if (length < maxLength) {
                //if length is less them maxLength then add typed alphanumeric char to hidden value
                var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
                $(".hidpassw").val($(".hidpassw").val() + character);
            }
        }
    });

    //special case for backspace
    $("body").on("keydown", ".pass", function (e) {
        var code = e.which;
        var length = $(".hidpassw").val().length;
        if (code === 8) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (length > 0) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                $(".hidpassw").val($(".hidpassw").val().substring(0, length - 1));
                $(".pass").val(createMask($(".hidpassw").val()));
            }
        }
    });


    $("body").on("keyup", ".pass", function (e) {
        var length = $(".hidpassw").val().length;
        if (length <= maxLength) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            //show last typed char for 100ms and then mask it
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $(".pass").val(createMask($(".hidpassw").val()));
            }, 100);
        }
    });
});
```