# How to show password characters on password protected Wordpress Page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a password protected public facing page on Wordpress that works perfectly.  However I would like the password characters to show as the user is typing them in.  How do I show the characters and not the default dots?

Comment: Can you share the url or the code for the login form.

Comment: The best way to reach this, is to add some JavaScript logic to switch the type of the input field from password to text. This way you will be able to see the password.

Comment: Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186309/make-password-textbox-value-visible-after-each-character-input